# Get user name when using customUserNamePasswordValidatorType

Tags: c#, wcf

I have been creating a WCF web service. I use a custom serviceCredential :

```
<serviceCredentials>
    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                            customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyNameSpace.CredentialsChecker"/>
</serviceCredentials>
```

I have my class CredentialChecker

```
public class CredentialsChecker : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {...}
}
```

It works good but I want to know the `userName` in my `Service1.svc`. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer :

```
String username = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
```

It can be used everywhere.